# ActiveMQ amqp+ssl in Quarkus JMS

Tags: ssl, jms, activemq-classic, quarkus, amqp

I have a problem with use my ActiveMQ broker in Quarkus app. To first usage I wanna try example from the [official website](https://quarkus.io/guides/jms), and I have everything exactly like in examples (`PriceConsumer`, `PriceProducer`, `Resource`, `quarkus-qpid-jms` dependency, and `quarkus.qpid-jms` - username/password), except `quarkus.qpid-jms.url`, because there are endpoints with **amqp**, but I can't use that, I have endpoints with **amqp+ssl** protocols.

When I've tried run application with this endpoints, it return errors:

```
"loggerName":"org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderFactory",
"level":"ERROR",
"message":"Failed to create Provider instance for amqp+ssl, due to: {}",
"threadName":"FailoverProvider: async work thread",
(...)
"exception":{"refId":1,"exceptionType":"java.io.IOException","message":"Provider scheme NOT recognized: [amqp+ssl]"
```

How could I configure that example for amqp+ssl in Quarkus?
It sounds easy, but I couldn't find anything about that (and I'm a really beginner in brokers topic).
All protocols which I have to my ActiveMQ: **amqp+ssl** / **ssl** / **wss** / **mqtt+ssl** / **stomp+ssl**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qpid JMS client you're using doesn't support the scheme `amqp+ssl` (as noted in the exception's message). You need to use `amqps` instead as noted in [the documentation](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-2.0.0/docs/index.html#connection-uri).

Keep in mind that the connector configuration in your `activemq.xml` (e.g. `amqp+ssl`, `ssl`, `wss`, `mqtt+ssl`, `stomp+ssl`) is for the **broker only**. Each client implementation has its own unique connection support whether than be via a URL or something else. You can't use the broker's configuration on a client and expect it to work.

Comment: Okay, it helped me understand my mistake, thank You. Unfortunetly connection still doesn't work, I've tried connect from Spring (by ssl protocol) and everything's been worked. Do You know about something more to configure for amqps? I know it's probably hard to say without more information, but I'm using amazonmq, so certs aren't needed. On Spring I didn't pass nothing except user, password, and endpoint.

Comment: What error are you getting now that you're using `amqps`?

Comment: I have nothing, this is why I don't know what could I do more, there is just a lot of attempts like: `Connection attempt:[1] to: amqps://link:5671 failed` . And at the end `javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: connection timed out`.
I've been tried to use `quarkus-artemis-jms` too, it allows only tcp schema, so I tried endpoint like `tcp://link:61617?sslEnabled=true`, but it doesn't make anything. 
I thought maybe something isn't configured on MQ - that's why I've checked it with springboot.

Comment: Are you using ActiveMQ Artemis or ActiveMQ "Classic" as your broker? Previous information indicates you're using "Classic" which means that `quarkus-artemis-jms` won't work under any circumstances.

Comment: So you can use `amqps://link:5671` with the Qpid JMS client successfully from Spring but not from Quarkus?

Comment: I've used other endpoint from spring - `ssl://link:61617`, but if `qpid-jms` needs `amqps` so I tried endpoint `amqps://link:5671` (I have information that it's configured on MQ).  I'm using Classic ActiveMQ, so I'm gonna give up trying with artemis, thanks!

Comment: If you use `ssl://link:61617` from Spring then you're using a different client (i.e. not Qpid JMS) and a different port. That really doesn't prove anything related to AMQP and SSL. If `amqps://link:5671` is failing with `connection timed out` that indicates an environmental problem (e.g. broker isn't listening on port `5671`, network connection is failing, etc.).